# fedora 15 intel legacy driver

Tags: video, fedora, gnome-shell

So I installed fedora 15 and intel video card driver seemed to work properly until I installed few windows programs through wine and saw video card issues in ms office. some black lines that broke the interface. but still functionality fully works. so I generated xorg.conf, changed driver from "intel" to "intellegacy" and placed in /etc/X11 folder. after restart I could enter only in fallback mode. from release notes of fedora 15 I read it: "In situations where properly supported 3D acceleration is not detected, GNOME 3 offers a fallback mode that models the GNOME Shell behavior". further more with intellegacy driver in fallback mode my cursor is blinking. how can I restore gnome shell work with this driver and how to resolve other issues?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this `intellegacy` driver you are using doesn't support 3D acceleration, in which case you will enter fallback mode. There is work ongoing to support Gnome Shell with software 3D rendering but until then you are stuck with fallback mode I'm afraid.

Where did this driver come from anyway? There is no driver by that name in the Fedora 15 repositories.